# Backup Access Database Daily/Weekly

Tags: ms-access, backup

We have a Microsoft Access database split into backend/frontend.  What I am looking for is to be able to automatically backup these files on a daily or weekly basis - what is the best way to go about this?  We don't want to have to worry about backups for the database, just know that it is occuring automatically on a schedule.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

(Borrowing from my earlier answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268611/backup-access-database-using-php-script)...)

**re: actually performing the backup**

Backing up a native Access database is simply a matter of copying the entire database file (.mdb for Access_2003 and earlier, .accdb for Access_2007 and later). Any scripting language would work, even a simple Windows batch file that does something like

```
copy /Y d:\apps\databases\mydatabase.accdb z:\backups\databases\*.*
```

**re: automatic scheduling of the backup**

The Task Scheduler in Windows could take care of that for you. Once you've created your script to copy the database file(s) you can create a scheduled task to run it periodically. See the MSDN article [Using the Task Scheduler (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384006%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: that's basically what I'm after. Is there any issue with the database being split into frontend/backend? What if it's in use at the time of backup? Thanks.

Comment: [1] re: frontend/backend -- The backend file is the one that constantly changes, so that's the one that needs (more) regular backups. [2] re: file (may be) in use -- There is no simple answer to that one. Shared-file databases do not have the same advantages as client-server databases in that regard.

Comment: What does this mean ? Is it possible to copy it while in use?

Comment: @Parhs Yes, it is possible to copy an Access database file while it is in use (unless it has been opened as Exclusive). However, copying *any* file while it is actively in use is usually not a good idea.

Comment: you mean that it can be corrupted ? Like having 7 users

Comment: @Parhs While it is most unlikely that the source (original) file would get corrupted, the destination file might not be a reliable backup if writes were happening on the source file while it was being copied.

Comment: So copied file might be corrupt ?

Comment: @Parhs It's possible, yes.

Comment: That means that you should tell everyone to close MS Access while backup is being taken ?

Answer (score 5):

You can write a sub to backup the database to a specified folder and run this sub when the database is launched. There are a lot of ways to do this, but I personally use the following:

```
Function fMakeBackup() As Boolean

    Dim Source As String
    Dim Target As String
    Dim retval As Integer


    Source = CurrentDb.Name

    Target = "Z:\My Apps\Backups\YourFielName"
    Target = Target & Format(Date, "mm-dd") & "   "
    Target = Target & Format(Time, "hh-mm") & ".accdb"

    ' create the backup
    retval = 0
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    retval = objFSO.CopyFile(Source, Target, True)
    Set objFSO = Nothing

End Function
```