# Referring to a network location without volume label in VBA for Access 2013

Tags: backup, ms-access

I run a database at work in Access 2013. The VBA corrupted after a day from the amount of people using it, so I attempted to split the database to solve the problem. The split worked after I decompiled the database, but then when other users tried to access it, the front end couldn't find the back end. This is because we all have the network drive it is mounted on assigned a different volume label - ie mine is set to W:/ and others have H:/, X:/, etc.

As the database splitting is a built-in function, as far as I could see there is no way to edit the attributes of the split, or even choose where to save the back-end. I'm pretty sure there's no way around this (but if there is, please let me know) so instead I'm just going to make sure I back up the database every day. I found some code for it in this thread [Backup Access Database Daily/Weekly](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/37368/backup-access-database-daily-weekly)

Which backs the database up every time it's opened, but again it refers to the location to back it up in with the specific volume label. Is there any way to refer to the location by its full location address rather than W:\location? The full name of the network drive looks something like \filesvr2\NetworkFolder\SubFolder\Database

Any help with my first post would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Using the Linked Table Manager dialog, you can relink the front-end to the back end tables.  When you browse to select the back-end file, use a standard UNC network path instead of mapped drives.  For example, you would browse to

```
"\filesvr2\NetworkFolder\SubFolder\Database.accdb"
```

.  This makes the front-end portable between any PC on your LAN that can resolve that file server by name.